# Azure ML Studio ML Pipeline - Exception: No temp file found

Tags: azure, machine-learning, nlp, etl, ml-studio

I've successfully run an ML Pipeline experiment and published the Azure ML Pipeline without issues.  When I run the following directly after the successful run and publish (i.e. I'm running all cells using Jupyter), the test fails!

```
interactive_auth = InteractiveLoginAuthentication()
auth_header = interactive_auth.get_authentication_header()

rest_endpoint = published_pipeline.endpoint
response = requests.post(rest_endpoint, 
                         headers=auth_header, 
                         json={"ExperimentName": "***redacted***",
                               "ParameterAssignments": {"process_count_per_node": 6}})
run_id = response.json()["Id"]
```

Here is the error in azureml-logs/70_driver_log.txt:

```
[2020-12-10T17:17:50.124303] The experiment failed. Finalizing run...
Cleaning up all outstanding Run operations, waiting 900.0 seconds
3 items cleaning up...
Cleanup took 0.20258069038391113 seconds
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "driver/amlbi_main.py", line 48, in <module>
    main()
  File "driver/amlbi_main.py", line 44, in main
    JobStarter().start_job()
  File "/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/***redacted***/azureml/***redacted***/mounts/workspaceblobstore/azureml/***redacted***/driver/job_starter.py", line 52, in start_job
    job.start()
  File "/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/***redacted***/azureml/***redacted***/mounts/workspaceblobstore/azureml/***redacted***/driver/job.py", line 105, in start
    master.wait()
  File "/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/***redacted***/azureml/***redacted***/mounts/workspaceblobstore/azureml/***redacted***/driver/master.py", line 301, in wait
    file_helper.start()
  File "/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/***redacted***/azureml/***redacted***/mounts/workspaceblobstore/azureml/***redacted***/driver/file_helper.py", line 206, in start
    self.analyze_source()
  File "/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/***redacted***/azureml/***redacted***/mounts/workspaceblobstore/azureml/***redacted***/driver/file_helper.py", line 69, in analyze_source
    raise Exception(message)
Exception: No temp file found. The job failed. A job should generate temp files or should fail before this. Please check logs for the cause.
```

**Exception: No temp file found. The job failed. A job should generate temp files or should fail before this. Please check logs for the cause.**

Here are the errors in logs/sys/warning.txt:

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 429 Client Error: Too Many Requests for url: https://eastus.experiments.azureml.net/execution/v1.0/subscriptions/***redacted***/resourceGroups/***redacted***/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/***redacted***/experiments/***redacted-experiment-name***/runs/***redacted-run-id***/telemetry
```

[...]

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url:
```

with the same URL.

**Next...**

When I wait a few minutes and rerun the following code/cell.

```
interactive_auth = InteractiveLoginAuthentication()
auth_header = interactive_auth.get_authentication_header()

rest_endpoint = published_pipeline.endpoint
response = requests.post(rest_endpoint, 
                         headers=auth_header, 
                         json={"ExperimentName": "***redacted***",
                               "ParameterAssignments": {"process_count_per_node": 2}})
run_id = response.json()["Id"]
```

**It completes successfully!?  Huh?**  (*I changed the process count here, but I don't think that makes a difference*).  Also, there is no user error here in the logs.

Any ideas as to what could be going on here?

Thanks in advance for any insights you might have, and happy coding! :)

**========== UPDATE #1: ==========**

Running on 1 file with ~300k rows.  Sometimes the job works and sometimes it doesn't.  We've tried many versions with different config settings, all result in a failure from time to time.  Changed sklearn models to use n_jobs=1.  We're scoring text data for NLP work.

```
default_ds = ws.get_default_datastore()

# output dataset
output_dir = OutputFileDatasetConfig(destination=(def_file_store, 'model/results')).register_on_complete(name='model_inferences')

# location of scoring script
experiment_folder = 'model_pipeline'    

rit = 60*60*24

parallel_run_config = ParallelRunConfig(
    source_directory=experiment_folder,
    entry_script="score.py",
    mini_batch_size="5",
    error_threshold=10,
    output_action="append_row",
    environment=batch_env,
    compute_target=compute_target,
    node_count=5,
    run_invocation_timeout=rit,
    process_count_per_node=1
)
```

Our next test was going to be - chuck each row of data into its own file.  I tried this with just 30 rows i.e. 30 files each with 1 record for scoring, and still getting the same error.  This time I changed the error threshold to 1.

```
2020-12-17 02:26:16,721|ParallelRunStep.ProgressSummary|INFO|112|The ParallelRunStep processed all mini batches. There are 6 mini batches with 30 items. Processed 6 mini batches containing 30 items, 30 succeeded, 0 failed. The error threshold is 1. 
2020-12-17 02:26:16,722|ParallelRunStep.Telemetry|INFO|112|Start concatenating.
2020-12-17 02:26:17,202|ParallelRunStep.FileHelper|ERROR|112|No temp file found. The job failed. A job should generate temp files or should fail before this. Please check logs for the cause.
2020-12-17 02:26:17,368|ParallelRunStep.Telemetry|INFO|112|Run status: Running
2020-12-17 02:26:17,495|ParallelRunStep.Telemetry|ERROR|112|Exception occurred executing job: No temp file found. The job failed. A job should generate temp files or should fail before this. Please check logs for the cause..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/**redacted**/mounts/workspaceblobstore/azureml/**redacted**/driver/job.py", line 105, in start
    master.wait()
  File "/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/**redacted**/mounts/workspaceblobstore/azureml/**redacted**/driver/master.py", line 301, in wait
    file_helper.start()
  File "/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/**redacted**/mounts/workspaceblobstore/azureml/**redacted**/driver/file_helper.py", line 206, in start
    self.analyze_source()
  File "/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/**redacted**/mounts/workspaceblobstore/azureml/**redacted**/driver/file_helper.py", line 69, in analyze_source
    raise Exception(message)
Exception: No temp file found. The job failed. A job should generate temp files or should fail before this. Please check logs for the cause.
```

And on the rounds where it does complete, only some of the records are returned.  One time the # of records returned I think was 25 or 23, and another time it was 15.

**========== UPDATE #2: 12/17/2020 ==========**

I removed one of my models (my model is a weight blend of 15 models). I even cleaned up my text fields, removing all tabs, newlines, and commas.  Now I'm scoring 30 files, each with 1 record, and the job completes sometimes, but it doesn't return 30 records.  Other times it returns an error, and still getting "No temp file found" error.

Comment: Can you please add more details about the training. ParallelRunStep uses multiple cores on one machine.

process_count_per_node in PipelineRunConfig is used to define how many processes PRS starts to run the tasks (mini batches). For example, set this to 2, there will be two tasks running in parallel on one node.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/tutorial-pipeline-batch-scoring-classification

Comment: See updates in posted question.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I might have answered my own question.  I think the issue was with

```
OutputFileDatasetConfig
```

Once I switched back to using

```
PipelineData
```

Everything started working again.  I guess Azure wasn't kidding when they say that OutputFileDatasetConfig is still experimental.

The thing I still don't understand is how we're supposed to pick up the results of an ML Studio Pipeline from a Data Factory Pipeline without OutputFileDatasetConfig?  PipelineData outputs the results in a folder based on the child step run id, so how is Data Factory supposed to know where to get the results?  Would love to hear any feedback anyone might have.  Thanks :)

**== Update ==**

For picking up results of an ML Studio Pipeline from a Data Factory Pipeline, check out [Pick up Results From ML Studio Pipeline in Data Factory Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65362041/pick-up-results-from-ml-studio-pipeline-in-data-factory-pipeline)

**== Update #2 ==**

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/16568#issuecomment-781526789

> Hi @yeamusic21 , thank you for your feedback, in current version,
> OutputDatasetConfig can't work with ParallelRunStep, we are working on
> fixing it.